# How could I create an action will happen a while in parallel with my main action?

Tags: python

I'm creating a little game where we can fight with characters. But, like in many game of fight turn per turn, I want create some action will occured a certain amout of time. For example, an action will change a stat for 3 turn or less/more. If someone can help me please.
                                                       Thank you

Comment: The [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Turns aren't usually based on time so you might not need threading. This is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Log of scheduled actions

What you seem to need (causing an effect that will happen after a certain number of turns) is a log of scheduled actions.

One way to implement it is to keep a list of "active effects".

For a crude example,

```
# in the beginning
active_effects = []

# when the effect is caused
active_effects.append( { 'turn' : current_turn + 3, 'target' : 'player', 'damage' : 10 } )

# at the start of every turn
for effect in active_effects:
    if effect['turn'] == current_turn:
         apply_effect(effect)
```

(you might want to use a class instead and specify the effect as a function, but this should illustrate the general concept).

Comment: You cannot `add` to a list. You mean `append`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it answer at another question I haved. But I think I have not explain correctly my question. I want to an effect apply a certain amount of turn, for example, reduce by 5 the "defense" of a character for 3 turn.             Thank you to have answer at my question.

Comment: @Exaye (and roganjosh) I updated the code sample to adjust for these things.